# What is the NSAboutURLProtocol class

Tags: cocoa, nsurlprotocol

When testing out my own `URLProtocol` subclass, I printed a list of the other subclasses the system knows about.  I saw a "`NSAboutURLProtocol`" there.  Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 0):

I think it handles the ["about:" URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme), though I have no idea what "handles" means in this context.  It probably returns a blank document with a 200 status code or something.